Finding $f$ orthogonal to set.
Let $A \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}$. Consider the following set of functions $$M = \{e^{2 \pi in x}\}_{n \in A} \cup \{xe^{2 \pi i n x}\}_{n \in A^c}$$ belonging to $L^2[0, 1]$. Does there exists a function $f \neq 0$ such that $f \perp M$?
Suppose that $f \perp M$ existed, then we would have the following representations:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in A^c} \hat{f}(n)e^{2 \pi i n x} \quad \text{and} \quad xf(x) = \sum_{n \in A} (xf(x))^{\wedge}(n)e^{2 \pi i n x}.$$ Can we conclude anything from here? It seems like we could, however I do not know if there is a counterexample to this.

There’s no such $f$. Indeed, assume to the contrary. Let $P_f$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span}\{f\}$, and let $M_x$ be multiplication by $x$. Note that the assumptions imply $xf \perp f$, so $P_fM_xP_f = 0$, but then,
$$(M_{\sqrt{x}}P_f)^\ast(M_{\sqrt{x}}P_f) = P_fM_xP_f = 0$$
So $M_{\sqrt{x}}P_f = 0$. In particular, $\sqrt{x}f = 0$, which implies $f = 0$, a contradiction.

@RyszardSzwarc provided a simple, direct argument in the comments below. Here is another simplified argument, which is also readily generalizable to arbitrary injective positive operator in place of multiplication by $x$:
$$xf \perp f \Rightarrow 0 = \langle f, xf \rangle = \langle x^{1/2}f, x^{1/2}f \rangle \Rightarrow x^{1/2}f = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$$
Fundamentally, the core of all three arguments is more or less the same - you cannot rotate something by $90$ degrees using something positive.

This implies that you may replace the Fourier basis by any other orthonormal basis, and replace $x$ by any other nonnegative function (or, more generally, any positive operator on $L^2[0, 1]$) which is nonzero a.e. (injective, in case of a general positive operator), and the result would still hold.

You can slightly simplify your reasoning. Since $xf\perp f$ then $\int_0^1x|f(x)|^2,dx=0.$ Hence $x|f(x)|^2=0,$ i.e. $f=0.$

@RyszardSzwarc You’re right. I suppose, being an operator algebraist, my mind sort of immediately went to the framing with positive operators. Your approach is quite simpler. Now that I’m looking at this again, there are a few other ways to simplify my argument as well.
